# Is it OK to access <style> and <script> elements in this way?

Tags: javascript, css

Is this good CSS practice?

`<style id="magic">` - so that I could, if I wanted - add CSS propreties using JavaScript (meaning: editing the `<style>` element from JavaScript) to affect elements in the document without me making the script go through each of the matched elements.

`<script style="display: block; white-space: pre;">` So that I could share scripts inside a blog post along with a demo, without me being forced to write a version for the blog post and an other one for the demo.

(This is just hypothetical)

Comment: I'm doing fine. Can you edit your question to make it more clear? It's not particularly obvious what you want to do, as well as being quite broad.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you are wondering is a good practice?

Comment: Try this on this page: javascript:$('script').css('display','block');

Comment: haha, come on! I was talking about a snippet that I would wanna share as a blog post, I would not show all the scripts just the one I want to

Comment: Ok, I finally understood the question...and I'd say it's definitely a non-recommended practice. I would suggest creating a `<div>` and copying the innerHTML of the `<script>`, why? probably just security reasons, tho it's not completely evil or anything.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's good or bad, it's a part of the w3c-DOM, so just do it if you want to.

Comment: @JCOC611 I'm not sure that a `<script>` even has a working .innerHTML property.  Although we'd have to test to find out.  Script is parsed differently to HTML content by the browser.

Comment: -1 for the terrible title, and for merging multiple questions into a single posting.

Comment: I tried improving the title, feel free to suggest something better though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first case (modifying style definitions in the `<style>` element using Javascript), you may find a couple of road bumps:

1. Different browsers cope with this differently.  In IE (at least, older versions), you will have to modify the `.styleSheet.cssText` property of the style element, and in other browsers you just need to add text nodes as children to it (note, it's possible that .innerHTML works universally; I just never used that).
2. Appending new style rules is easier than replacing existing ones, especially when you are treating the rules as just text.
3. Browsers (may) have a limit to the number of style rules per page.  Though this will be in the thousands, you could hit limits if you set up style rules in a loop (without somehow purging old ones).

Other than that, go for it.  It's probably a good alternative to setting inline styles.

---

In your second case, I'm sorry but that's just not possible (or if it is, it's definitely not recommended).  You cannot display the textual contents of a `<script>` element as text using CSS, as well as executing it as Javascript.  For a start, HTML parsers switch into a different mode while they're parsing the contents of a `<script>` element.

The preferred method for showing your Javascript source code alongside a demo is to have a separate, display-friendly version of the code for display (in a `<pre>` element, for example).